# Managing DroboShare SSH usernames and passwords

Tags: ssh, drobo, droboshare

The default login for SSH on the droboshare is a user name of `root` with a password of `giveit2me`. With the command passwd the password can be changed. However I can't find anyway to change the default user name. Since any Unix based has a user named `root` this kinda bugs me as a minor security issue.

Does anyone know how to change the user name for droboshare SSH logins? The SSH program being used is a variant of [dropbear](http://matt.ucc.asn.au/dropbear/dropbear.html) if that is any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be aware. Some NAS (qnap i know) use patched dropbear that allow only root user access from ssh.
Test, you can create different user and has ssh access with it.
If test ok. dropbear configured in init script. But each NAS may be is very specific.

Comment: Using `adduser username` and then `passwd username` allowed me to create a new user that could login via SSH. However the user root can still login. Is there any way to disable that?

Comment: On second thought since droboshare does not have any other way to login besides SSH disabling root access for SSH is a bad idea.

Comment: If different user can login over ssh.

Can new user escalate priveleges to root by su or sudo ?

If can is possible
  * foind init script where dropbear started and disable root login with -w option
  * disable root by setting shell to /bin/nologin
...

and then using logging in with different user and make su -s or sudo for use root priveleges.